# How to hide and show div in asp.net mvc 5 using dropdownlist change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to hide and show div in my mvc 5 project using dropdownlist change event, i have researched, and luckily i found this code online, but it doesn't seem to work for me, i will appreciate if anyone could point at where i am making mistakes.
Thanks in advance.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#CountryID").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "Ghana") {
                    $("#showStateLga").show();
                    $("#showStateLgaText").hide();
                } else {
                    $("#showStateLga").hide();
                    $("#showStateLgaText").show();
                } 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Dropdownlist control:

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.cCountryList, "---Select---", new {@class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Div Control:

```
 <div id="showStateLga" style="display: none">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.notState, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.notState, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.notState, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.notCity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.notCity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.notCity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Rendering Results:

Dropdownlist:

```
    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="CountryID">Country:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Country: must be a number." data-val-required="Select country" id="CountryID" name="CountryID"><option value="">---Select---</option>
                   <option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
                   <option value="2">Ghana</option>
                   <option value="3">Albania</option>
                   <option value="4">Algeria</option>
                       </select>
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CountryID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Div1:

```
    <div id="showStateLga" style="display:block">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="UserStateList">State:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <select class="form-control" id="State" name="State"><option value="">---Select State---</option>
                          <option value="1">Abia State</option>
                         <option value="2">Adamawa State</option>
                          <option value="3">Akwa Ibom State</option>

                        </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2"              for="UserCity">City:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <select id="lga" name="lga" class="form-control"    required>
                                <option value="">---Select LGA---</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Div2:

```
<div id="showStateLgaText" style="display:none">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="notNigeriaState">State:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Enter state" id="notNigeriaState" name="notNigeriaState" type="text" value="" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="notNigeriaState" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="notNigeriaCity">City:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Enter city" id="notNigeriaCity" name="notNigeriaCity" type="text" value="" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="notNigeriaCity" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. That is the value of $("#CountryID") is **CountryID** instead of **CountryName**.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#CountryID").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != "Ghana") { // It doesn't work over here.
                $("#showStateLga").show();
            } else {
                $("#showStateLga").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

There are 2 ways to fix it. First

```
if ($(this).val() != "2") { // Replace the match text to CountryID.
```

Or

```
if ($(this).find(':selected').text() != "Ghana") { // Replace .val() to .find(':selected').text().
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, only the .show() part that works now, after showing, the div refused to be hidden even. please is there any other thing i can do?

Comment: Could you give me the rendering results of both **Dropdownlist control** and **Div Control** parts?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by rendering result.

Comment: Generally, the codes prepended with **@html** are server-side program. So server will run the program and generate a perfect html file to browser. Anyway, **rendering result** means html source. 
By the way, why I need the result is the possible reason might be a UI issue.

Comment: The rendering result is too long to add as comment even when i have removed some part, i don't know how to send that to you now,

Comment: Use sandbox like jsfiddle or jsbin.

Comment: I don't know how to use those tools, but i have edited my question to include the rendering results. Thanks

Comment: I have found the reason of your issue. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: You rock, i am just laughing at my ignorance, that has resolve the issue, thank you very much, i really appreciate.