# can you add an if else statements in between <tr> tags in a .cshtml files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2015

I am writing a program in visual studio 2015, there is a dropdown in a table where a user can select values, I want to change the content of the next row based on the users selection by using an if else statement inside the  tag's  tag.
Is this possible ?

my code in cshtml:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownList(
            "Actions_performed", 
            new SelectList(ViewBag.Actions_performed, "Key", "Value"),
            "--select--", 
            new { @class = "form-control" });
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <!--make ajax here -->
        @if (Model.ActionSelected == "keyvalueofselectedaction")
        {
            string x = "this text";
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        else
        {
            string upload = "upload file here!";
            Console.WriteLine(upload);
        }
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: To answer shortly, yes. But yes/no questions aren't suited for Stack Overflow. If you need help with coding the solution, please update this post with more of your WIP code.

Comment: Yes, you can :)

Comment: Use jQuery/javascript to update the DOM based on the dropdown selection.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine();`?

Comment: but it is now visible in the front end that particular row is appearing just blank

Comment: You need javascript to respond to client side events!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: i was just experimenting with console writeline if i can print that string to the front end...i want the next row to reflect based on the value selected in drop down, so how do i write the if else statement after the drop down

Comment: JavaScript, which has been mentioned twice so far. C# is executed on the server before serving the view to the client.a

Comment: selection happens at client side. So listen to the change event of the select element, get the value and do your if condition, use the appropriate jQuery selector ( look at `next`) to get a hold of the next row. Hide /show the text  or udpate the text as needed.

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080710/how-to-hide-and-show-div-in-asp-net-mvc-5-using-dropdownlist-change-event

Comment: @KrishnaU Not related to your actual problem, but if you want to output an expression to the page in Razor you can add an `@` before it. For example `@x` will "print" the value of `x` to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Console.WriteLine it's for console applications, not web applications.

Razor allows you to write HTML inside the { and }.
You can also use Html.Raw("<b>raw html here</b>");

More info here: https://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c