# Show/hide div according to DropDownListFor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need help with changing the visibility of 2 `div` elements according to the selected value in DropDownListFor.

Let's say, in dropDown there are values "One", "Two" and "Three".

- I want to show the `div` `id="time"` when the value of "One" or "Two" is selected and hide `div` `id="fromTo"`
- When the value "Three" is selected, I want to show `div` `id="fromTo"` and hide `div` `id="time"`.

This is the code I currently have:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.I_Uloha, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UlohaString, (SelectList)ViewBag.Tasks, new { @class = "form-control"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.I_Uloha, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>


<div id="time" class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Zataz, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Zataz, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Zataz, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>

<div id="fromTo">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.D_Zac, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.D_Zac, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.D_Zac, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.D_Kon, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.D_Kon, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.D_Kon, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need Jquery code for that dude

Comment: Use JS for hide div elements depending on DDL value. Example: `var value = $("#UlohaString").val(); if (value == 1 || value == 2) { $('#fromTo').hide(); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use jQuery `show()` & `hide()` methods to change visibility of `div` elements in view page depending from drop down list value like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#UlohaString').change(function () {
        var ddlValue = $(this).val();

        if (ddlValue == "One" || ddlValue == "Two")
        {
            // show time div, hide fromTo div
            $('#time').show();
            $('#fromTo').hide();
        }
        else if (ddlValue == "Three")
        {
            // show fromTo div, hide time div
            $('#fromTo').show();
            $('#time').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Note that `var ddlValue = $(this).find(':selected').text()` can be used if `$(this).val()` doesn't work here.

Reference:

[How to hide and show div in asp.net mvc 5 using dropdownlist change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080710/how-to-hide-and-show-div-in-asp-net-mvc-5-using-dropdownlist-change-event)

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would like to point out that jQuery show() & hide() methods are not needed here. They are certainly representing a solution, but not without alternative. One can solve this without jQuery at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using javascript and call it from your razor elements

```
@Html.DropDownListFor("Someidorname", null, "Select Your value", new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "clickMe()" })
```

Javascript

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
 function clickMe()
 {
    var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
    var ddlValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if(ddlValue =="x") 
    {
        document.getElementById("attid").style.display = 'none';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("attid").style.display = 'none';
    } 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check Below Jquery Code for achieve this :**

You can use  ".css('display', 'none')"  for hide your div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#UlohaString').change(function () {
                var drpValue = $("#UlohaString").val();
                if (drpValue == 1 || drpValue == 2)
                {
                    $('#fromTo').css('display', 'none');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#fromTo').css('display', 'block');
                }

            });
 });
</script>
```

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use jQuery to achieve this.

```
<script>
    // use @Html.IdFor so this does not break 
    // if you rename the UlohaString property in the ViewModel
    var dropdown = $('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.UlohaString)');

    dropdown.on('change', function () {
        // this gets the "value" attribute of the selected option
        // if you need the text, use .text() instead of .val()
        var selected = $('option:selected', dropdown).val();

        // best practice to use === instead of == for comparisons
        if (selected === 'One' || selected === 'Two') {
            $('#time').show();
            $('#fromTo').hide();
        } 
        else if (selected === 'Three') {
             $('#time').hide();
             $('#fromTo').show();
        }
    }
</script>
```